# ROV competition camera real time video processing

Tags: video, camera, video-processing

ROV competetion requires supporting the underwater ROV with camera , which is used to find certain objects ( some numbers , plates ,measuring some distances... etc)

I want to learn about how to make a software to help finding these objects , for example alerts me when a number or  shows up .

I'm asking where to start learning ?! Do I have to learn Matlab ?!

I prefer using java if it can help doing the job by the way .